# Validation before bulkinsert in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want to import data from text file.which contain arround lakhs of records

I am using bulk insert do it like this

```
BULK
INSERT vw_bulk_insert_test
FROM '\\server\c$\csvtext.txt'--\\server\SQLEXPRESS\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(FIRSTROW=2,
check_CONSTRAINTS,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '~',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

But before insert I want to validate values of each column without using cursor.Like if second row will have values of all fields except unit_number(Column) then it should create a error log specifying unit_number value is missing.

Comment: "lac" is a regional term, not commonly understood by most of the readers of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would bulk-insert into a temp table, and then do validations/conversions from the temp table into the table where things will ultimately reside using either TSQL or TSQL in the form of stored procedures created for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have this syntax

```
BULK INSERT 
   [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] [ table_name | view_name ] 
      FROM 'data_file' 
     [ WITH 
    ( 
   [ [ , ] BATCHSIZE = batch_size ] 
   [ [ , ] CHECK_CONSTRAINTS ] 
   [ [ , ] CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ] 
   [ [ , ] DATAFILETYPE = 
      { 'char' | 'native'| 'widechar' | 'widenative' } ] 
   [ [ , ] FIELDTERMINATOR = 'field_terminator' ] 
   [ [ , ] FIRSTROW = first_row ] 
   [ [ , ] FIRE_TRIGGERS ] 
   [ [ , ] FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' ] 
   [ [ , ] KEEPIDENTITY ] 
   [ [ , ] KEEPNULLS ] 
   [ [ , ] KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH = kilobytes_per_batch ] 
   [ [ , ] LASTROW = last_row ] 
   [ [ , ] MAXERRORS = max_errors ] 
   [ [ , ] ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n ] ) ] 
   [ [ , ] ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ] 
   [ [ , ] ROWTERMINATOR = 'row_terminator' ] 
   [ [ , ] TABLOCK ] 
   [ [ , ] ERRORFILE = 'file_name' ] 
    )]
```